# How to get friend list using facebook graph api version 3.3?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have access-token and using 3.3 version of facebook graph API. I am unable to get the friendlist of user. Can somebody help me to get friend list of person so that I can send them an invitation to install my app.

Answer (score 0):

If it´s a game, you can use the Game Request dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests/

If not, use one of the Sharing Options described in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/

**There is no way to get the friends with the API anymore, you can only access friends who authorized your App too - with the `user_friends` permission.**